# How to create new records using Nested_form for existing model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form, nested-forms

**My scenario:**
I have 3 level hierarchy structure Eg: Grandparents, parents, children. 
At the initial stages, i created grandparents and parents records using `nested_form`. After creating the records i want to create children records for every parent using `nested_form`. 
So i went to parent record and tried creating children record. But here is what i am facing problem.

1. When i used `@parents = Parent.new` object for `nested_form`, i am getting `stack level too deep error`.
2. When i am trying to use `@parents = Parent.find(params[:id])` object, my children objects are getting over written, as its updating.

How to go about this ? I want to create new children records, for each parent without disturbing old children records(if any).

**Code:**

My helper method code:

```
@parents = Parent.new
  @parents.childrens.build
```

My view for parents, `show.html.erb`:

```
<div class="form-inputs well" style="background-color:white; border: solid 1px">
<%= simple_nested_form_for @parents do |f| %>
 <%= f.simple_fields_for :childrens do |ff| %>
 <div class="well">
  <table>
   <tr>
    <td> <i class="fa fa-check" style="margin-right:10px"></i> </td>
    <td> <%= ff.input :first_name, input_html: { style: "width:140px"} %> </td>
    <td> <%= ff.input :last_name, input_html: { style: "width:140px"}  %></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td> </td>
    <td> <%= ff.input :email, input_html: { style: "width:140px"} %> </td>
    <td> <%= ff.link_to_remove raw('<i class="fa fa-times-circle" style = "margin:0 0 25px 10px; opacity:0.5" ></i>') %> </td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </div> 
 <%end%>
 <%= f.link_to_add raw('<i class="fa fa-plus-square"> Add a child</i>'), :childrens, class: "btn btn-info", style: "position:relative; left:230px" %>
 <%= f.submit "Create", class: 'btn btn-success', style: "position:relative; right:80px" %>
<%end%>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the way, its simple. I had to use below code in my helper method but with a slight twist in view by adding  this extra line condition `<% if ff.object.new_record? %>`, after `<%= f.simple_fields_for :childrens do |ff| %>` which will only show the new records without old records. So that, there is no over written when updating.

```
@team = Team.find(params[:id])
@team.team_members.build
```